# Google Apps Script - Connect to external API by using a token received at login

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm trying to work with an external API and can't make it work after the first step.
The API is for an affiliate marketing platform, 2Performant, and supports only JSON format.
The first step is to login.
In response several headers are received that define the session.
These are: access-token | client | expiry | token-type | uid

In the next request I need to inject mandatory access-token | client | uid headers.

I managed to do the first step but get an error for my second one.
This is the code that I'm using.

```js
function apiconnect() {
 var url = "https://api.2performant.com/users/sign_in.json";
 var data =  {
    "user": {
       "email": "mail@example.com",
       "password": "mypassword"
     }
 };
 var options = {
   "method" : "post",
   "contentType" : "application/json",
   "payload" : JSON.stringify(data)
  
 };
 
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
 var text = response.getResponseCode();
 var token = response.getHeaders()["access-token"];
 var client = response.getHeaders()["client"];
 var uid = response.getHeaders()["uid"];
 Logger.log(text);
 Logger.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText()));
 Logger.log(response.getHeaders());
 Logger.log(token);
 Logger.log(client);
 Logger.log(uid);
 var urlPrograms = "https://api.2performant.com/affiliate/programs";
 var optionsPrograms = {
   "contentType" : "application/json",
   "headers" : {"access-token": token,
   "client" : client,
   "uid" : uid,
   }
 };
 
Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlPrograms,optionsPrograms));
}
```

For the first part I can see the correct responses in the logs but I'm getting an error for the second one. The error is 500 (Internal Server Error).
I've noticed that I get a 401 code ("Provided session is not valid anymore either does not exist at all") if I put a random text instead of the correct one in one of the three needed headers (uid, password or token).

By using curl in the terminal, the second step works, but I can't manage to translate this in the Apps Script.
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"email":"mail@example.com","password":"mypassword"}}' -i https://api.2performant.com/users/sign_in.json

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "access-token: 12345" -H "client: 123" -H "uid: mail@example.com" -i https://api.2performant.com/affiliate/programs

It's probably obvious that i'm not experienced in this so hopefully I was clear enough with my description.
If you can point me to the right direction to replicate the curl in apps script that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that your 2nd UrlFetchApp is the same request of your 2nd curl command. Although, unfortunately I cannot understand about `a random text instead of the correct one in one of the three needed headers`, for example, if you use the values of `token`, `client` and `uid` retrieved from your 1st UrlFetchApp to your 2nd curl command, what result will you obtain?

Comment: By random text, I mean that instead of "access-token" : token, I put something like "access-token" : "12345". So, basically, I noticed that if the three are correct I get a "internal server error", if not it will be a 401.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your replying.

Comment: It's probably my poor explanation, not your English skills. To answer your initial question, if I use the values of token, client and uid retrieved from the 1st UrlFetchApp, I still get a 500 (Internal Server Error)...

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was as simple as just adding .json to the second URL.